# I need to re-learn all highschool level mathemetics in order to attend college. (Please Help)

Tags: self-learning

I know this isn't a research level question, but a lot of you teach, and I'm not sure where else to turn.

I will just shoot straight: I am 30 years old. I have not done any type of true mathematics in over 10 years. In the preceding decade, I have forgotten everything I've ever known about mathematics.

Do any of you know of any sites that offer free lessons in algebra 1, geometry, etc?

Perhaps computer games that deal with high-school level math?

Again, I apologize for posting this here, but I'm anxious to restart my career as a student--something I can't do until I bring my math skills up to par.

Comment: What field do you intend to major in college? If it is a more mathematical field (like engineering, computer science or math) that you intend to major in, you would have to practice a lot more problems.  A good way to get back in touch with math is to (watch lectures online and then) solve lots of exercises.

Comment: At one point I was very good in math--I received a 35 on the math section of my ACT, but that was an eternity ago. I'm very, very out of practice. Do you know where I might find some grade 9-12 level lessons?

Comment: hmm, Space Integrators, Kac-Moody Algebra Man, probably endless

Answer (score 0):

Khan Academy is the easiest place to learn what you're after. The videos move slowly which I found annoying when I was studying Organic Chemistry and was looking for extra material. But if you are relearning math you may appreciate that quality.

edit: your tag of linear algebra is wrong - linear algebra is a college level course that is taken usually after the undergraduate calculus series is finished.

Also I would recommend playing math-oriented puzzle games if you want that type of resource. Here's something really simple while still offering problem solving which requires some deeper considerations (http://www.kongregate.com/games/GameScience/refraction), so long as you try to get the bonus coins.